# Is there a good way to get the original unsigned char value of a texture within the fragment shader

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want a way to make sure that I get the exact same uchar value I passed in for each channel when I initialized the texture, which I am guessing I could get by multiplying the float value by 255, but is there a better way to do this without OpenGL ES 3.0?

The purpose:
I am trying to use this for a non-realtime texture lookup based on the channel values which will require more than 8 bits of precision to get so I will be combining two channels and using pseudo binary operations to do it. I realize this will be very slow, but this is not a realtime operation.

Example Code:
Currently it is possible to use floating point only in textures to my knowlege.

```
float channel_value = texture2D(normalMap, textureCoord).a;
```

I would like to be able to do something which would have the equivalent of

```
int channel_value = texture2D(normalMap, textureCoord).a;
```

I could then do a fairly inefficient binary operation such as

```
mod(channel_val / pow(2, x), 2)
```

to check the bit values.

Comment: This is the review queue. I don't think its a bad question (if I am reading it correctly), but its a bit unclear to me (that's not surprising since I'm not a graphics guy). Perhaps you should sharpen it a bit before the question is closed. For example, what are you currently doing, and why is it a potential problem?

Comment: I added a purpose, but I believe the question was clear to those who are proficient at GLSL, which is the only audience who could answer or gain knowledge from the question. As such, I don't think the -1 was necessary.

Comment: Ok! Sorry, I misunderstood. Looks like someone else thought it was terrible question too :)

Comment: No problem. After you spend some time in the queses, you'll see what I mean about it. Many questions are just junk. This question was not like that, and I did not want to see it roughed up. But it was a tad bit unclear from the outside looking in. If you add a little code and explained where the potential problem lies, I'd be happy to upvote it for you. The additional information would likely help future OpenGL visitors who are less experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a more elegant way in ES 2.0. There is a very limited selection of texture formats, which does not include the integer texture formats you could use in ES 3.0.

To get the original integer value in the shader, you need to be careful about the rounding. In theory, multiplying by 255.0 will give you the original value, but there are always precision limitations when dealing with floating point. Since the cast from `float` to `int` rounds down, I would add 0.5 to make sure that your round to the closest `int`:

```
vec4 floatVal = texture2D(...);
ivec4 intVal = ivec4(floatVal * 255.0 + 0.5);
```

If you want original values back, you will also need to make sure that you use `GL_NEAREST` for the filtering parameters. Otherwise the samples values will be interpolated, and converting them to `int` will not necessarily give you any value that was originally in the texture data.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the rounding. I may experiment and see if it is needed or not. I had forgotten about GL_NEAREST which is a great call!